# Screen Glitches (random lines) ubuntu 18.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, display, screen

My Ubuntu 18.04 machine has random lines (horizontal usually) on it after waking up. All I have to do to get rid most of them is to reboot. Are there any other solutions to this problem?
Some apps such as chrome, or Spotify are always broken with these kinds of lines all over and they flicked back and forth between the app and a black box on my screen and a restart won't help either. I'm thinking it's a driver issue but I have reinstalled the driver a few times and no luck so far. [A folder with an array of lines on the side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4XCKX.png)

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 9bc4 (rev 05)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 1fb9 (rev a1)
```

Drivers

```
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: NVIDIA Corporation
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
       resources: irq:154 memory:b3000000-b3ffffff memory:70000000-7fffffff memory:80000000-81ffffff ioport:3000(size=128) memory:b4000000-b407ffff
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       logical name: /dev/fb0
       version: 05
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom fb
       configuration: depth=32 driver=i915 latency=0 mode=1920x1080 visual=truecolor xres=1920 yres=1080
       resources: iomemory:600-5ff iomemory:400-3ff irq:153 memory:604a000000-604affffff memory:4000000000-400fffffff ioport:4000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
```

Comment: what graphics card do you have and what driver do you use? please edit your question and add what type of setup and specs you have.

Comment: Does it happens when using, prior to suspending, the Intel, the Nvidia, or both?

Comment: @ChanganAuto currently my system is on intel and this happens, previously when I changed to Nividia using NVIDIA X Server Setting, the laptop won't boot in the graphic mode and I had to go back to intel using the console/tty so that's another set of issue.

Comment: Yes, that issue likely has to do with Secure Boot enabled. Disable it and Nvidia should work provided the correct, recommended, drivers are installed.

Comment: it's a work laptop and I don't have permission to disable the secure boot.